# SpringBoot with Gradle missing dependency for Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to setup a very simple Springboot application using Thymeleaf as my templating engine. I am %100 certain my @Controller is working fine but when I try to access the default url ("/") I get the dreaded "Whitelabel" error page.

Below is my gradle.build file...

```
buildscript {
     ext { springBootVersion = '1.4.0.RELEASE' }
     repositories { mavenCentral() }
     dependencies { classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
     baseName = 'masterSpringMvc'
     version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
repositories { mavenCentral() }

 dependencies {
     compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
     compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
     testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
 }

eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
}
```

Pretty sure I got everything setup right, so I go ahead and run the below build steps...

[image]

After this I am expecting to see the **spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf.jar** in my "Project and External Dependencies" but its not there. I'm very new to Gradle and was assuming that the build would pull in this required dependency, and then it would be "enabled" while starting my application. Any clue what I might be doing wrong here?

[image]

Here is my .html page, I am expecting to see "Test" displayed in the browser.

[image]

Comment: Just an FYI, I spent a few minutes to create a Maven based project that is exactly the same and it works fine (im pretty good with Maven but would like to know what I'm doing wrong with Gradle, its 99.9% related to not pulling in the dependency as mentioned in the post)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update dependencies.
On Package Explorer:
-> right click your project -> Gradle ->Enable Dependency Management -> right click it again -> Refresh Dependencies

Comment: Sorry for such a delay in response, I only had the option to Right click project -> Refresh Gradle Project, but that did the trick. So why doesn't a Gradle build do the same thing? What exactly is it for? Just building the actual deployable jar/war?